# when I held the assembly that women are fun I were just lying

Tags: grammar, american-english, speech, ellipses

"when I **held the assembly that** women are fun I were just lying"

The speaker had previously said so to an assembly of workmates.
What does the sentence mean?

The sentence can be heard (with the corresponding closed captions) at the [minute 11](https://youtu.be/p-Bb6lnekX0), on the third episode of the 20th season of South Park, which is on official page for free.

What **does hold sb that**... mean?

Could that represent the ellipsis for "at which I said"?

Here's the excerpt of the video: https://youtu.be/p-Bb6lnekX0
Here's the script: https://southpark.fandom.com/wiki/The_Damned/Script

Comment: I haven't listened to it, but I'm immediately certain that "held" is a mishearing (or possible a mis-speaking) for "told".

Comment: @ColinFine give it a listen then https://youtu.be/35VyB5DRIGg

Comment: I can't. It's unavailable.

Comment: @ColinFine I forgot to publish it public; here it is: https://youtu.be/p-Bb6lnekX0

Comment: The speech is intentionally garbled.  Plus there's that touch of Canajun accent/diction/idiom that South Park is somehow fond of.  (And note that "held to" is a legitimate though archaic substitute for "told".  Omitting the "to" would not be unusual in casual speech.)

Comment: @HotLicks Only one can be the solution, either the accent or the  ellipsis of "to"; regarding the second, in what dictionary can I find such a definition of "hold to" meaning "tell/say"?

Comment: The point it, it's pointless to worry about it.  South Park is not a standard reference for English speech.

Comment: @HotLicks I cannot find "hold to" meaning "tell/say" in a dictionary; could you help me please?

Comment: @GJC: You can **hold to** an opinion, i.e. "stick" to it, and you can **hold *that* such and such is a fact**, i.e. maintain or aver that it is true, but that's not what is being said there.

Comment: @TRomano - But you can "hold to" an audience "that such and such is a fact."

Comment: Was there a school assembly run by Cartman in a previous episode which was in essence a debate the topic of which was "Women are as funny as men" ?

Comment: @TRomano Yes there was

Comment: @GJC: There's the answer.

Comment: @TRomano Where?

Comment: I'm writing it now.

Answer (score 1):

The closed captions on the South Park site are not what you are quoting in your question:

> So, when you held the assembly...
>   that women were just as funny as men,
>   you weren't being sarcastic?

The pause between *assembly* and *that* indicates natural speech: she is thinking about what to say as she is speaking.

It seems some of her thoughts are elided, and what she says can readily be understood as:

> So, when you organised the assembly and you said
>   that women were just as funny as men, ...

Comment: According to @HotLicks "hold to" used to mean "say/tell"

Comment: @GJC - I never said that.

Comment: There's no pause between **assembly** and **that** as it is spoken there. The long pause comes after **that**.

Comment: @HotLicks Not literally. What you literally said was *"And note that 'held to' is a legitimate though archaic substitute for 'told'."* But if *held to* can mean *told*, then surely *hold to* can mean *tell*.

Comment: @JasonBassford - But not "say".

Answer (score 0):

Per OP, there was an assembly run by Cartman in a previous episode which was in essence a debate, the topic of which was the assertion "Women are as funny as men".

So, in the following statement

> So, when you held the assembly that women were just as funny as men, you weren't being sarcastic?

the phrase **held the assembly**  is *semantically* equivalent (in the speaker's mind) to **held the debate**.

Informally the verb **debate** can take a *that*-clause complement.

**We will debate <sup>(the proposition)</sup> that women are as funny as men.**

and the noun **debate** can be qualified or complemented quasi-adjectivally with a *that*-clause:

**The debate that women are as funny as men was a success.**

But some ellipsis could be involved along with this semantic recasting: "held the <strike>assembly</strike> debate *where you maintained* that ..."